# Write a SQL Query to find different users linked to same User ID

Tags: sql, hana

So I'm currently on a project where I'm working with multiple sources, and one of them is SAP data.
I need to return "duplicates" in essence and find all the different users, that are linked to the same SAP User ID. There are entries that are valid however, as the data describes access roles to the different SAP systems. So it is normal if the same user occurs more than once. But I need to find where there is a different name assigned to the same User ID.

This is what I currently have:

```
select *
   from (
      select *,
      row_number() over (partition by FULL_NAME order by USER_ID) as row_number 
from SAP_TABLE 
) as rows order by USER_ID desc
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would partition by the user_id

```
select *
   from (
      select *,
             count(distinct (full_name)) over (partition by user_id) as rnk 
        from SAP_TABLE 
        ) as rows 
 where rnk>1
  order by USER_ID desc
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - thank you! Stupid mistake on my side

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this?

```
    select count(distinct FULL_NAME),
           USER_ID
      from SAP_TABLE
  group by USER_ID
    having count(distinct FULL_NAME) > 1
```

Comment: damn we posted almost identical queries at the same time

Comment: Yes, exactly! How would I return the full dataset though with the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code to find all the user id's that occur more than once.

```sql
SELECT USER_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM SAP_TABLE
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```